# Inconsistent behavior while computing AGE in PostgreSQL?

Tags: postgresql

I am encountering different results while using AGE function in postgresql 9.1.

1. Incorrect. Two days are added when the current day is changed from Feb 28 to March 1st.

Query  : **select AGE ('2015-02-28', '2012-06-24');**
Result : **2 years 8 mons 4 days**

Query  : **select AGE ('2015-03-01', '2012-06-24');**
Result :  **2 years 8 mons 7 days**

2. Seems correct, when the age is computed from 2014-02-27. The extra days are not added here.

Query  :  **select AGE ('2015-02-28', '2014-02-27');**
Result : **1 year 1 day**

Query  : **select AGE ('2015-03-01', '2014-02-27');**
Result :  **1 year 2 days**

What must be happening while the query is being run?

Comment: I'm not saying it's a postgresql bug, but it surely looks like one..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The documentation says:

> PostgreSQL's approach uses the month from the earlier of the two dates when calculating partial months. For example, `age('2004-06-01', '2004-04-30')` uses April to yield 1 mon 1 day, while using May would yield 1 mon 2 days because May has 31 days, while April has only 30.

So for your example, the `2012-06-24`is your "earlier date" and the june has 30 days. So your difference computes as 24 to 30 is 6 and to 1 is 7.

This is not sane imho, but the `age()` function behaves exactly how it should according to the documentation.

**Edit:**

To be more precise: the `age()` function does **not** compute differences between dates. Don't use it to do that.

Comment: Yes, it's unfortunately inconsistent with working out the age by adding intervals onto the beginning date. It seems like it's really working out what interval has to be subtracted from the end date to get to the start date, rather than what interval has to be added to the start date to reach the end date. Not a good implementation, really.